# How to teach make4ht to understand newcommand properly?

Tags: miktex, make4ht, xhtml

[Make4ht](https://www.kodymirus.cz/samples/mathjaxnode/maths.html#x1-90007) without `/newcommand` within the document works pretty well with up and down indexes, see the case of `1_definition.html` in [This Git repository](https://github.com/KolosovPetro/TeXStackExchange)
[image]
But when the document involves, for example, a `\newcommand \coeffX [4][X]{\mathbf{#1}_{{#2},{#3}}(#4)}` the final result is done not so beautiful way, ie
[image]
where **X** is defined by `\newcommand \coeffX [4][X]{\mathbf{#1}_{{#2},{#3}}(#4)}`. See the case of `index.html` in [This Git repository](https://github.com/KolosovPetro/TeXStackExchange).

**Question:** *Is there any way to fix this issue?*

Comment: it is impossible to debug an image, please add a code block with a complete small document that makes that image

Comment: in particular, how are you calling `\coeffX`

Comment: I call it as: `\coeffX{m}{t}{j}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Source Files are added.

Comment: a small inline example is much better than a link to an external site, the question here is archived forever but the external link has fewer guarantees,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common issue regarding sub- and superscripts in TeX4ht. The `_` and  `^` characters are not active in the preamble, so commands defined here don't work correctly. It is best to use the `\sp` and `\sb` commands instead:

```
\newcommand \coeffX [4][X]{\mathbf{#1}\sb{#2,#3}(#4)}
```

This is the result:

[image]